# And Operator in parse Query

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to fetch only those objects from server with are matching say two fields. For that i need to have an `and` operator. I have no idea how to use an and operator on parse query. I have previously used an `Or` operator on parse query. 
An `Or` operator does opposite of what I require in my programme. I am giving an `Or` operator example below. Please tell me how to make the mainQuery  equal to whereContainedIn(myList1 AND myList2)

```
ParseQuery myQuery1 = new ParseQuery("myTable");
myQuery1.whereContainedIn("key", myList1);

ParseQuery myQuery2 = new ParseQuery("myTable");
myQuery2.whereContainedIn("key", myList2);

List<ParseQuery<ParseObject>> queries = new ArrayList<ParseQuery<ParseObject>>();
queries.add(myQuery1);
queries.add(myQuery2);

ParseQuery<ParseObject> mainQuery = ParseQuery.or(queries);
Now the mainQuery is equal to whereContainedIn(myList1 OR myList2)
```

Comment: call "whereContainedIn" 2 times on the same query object using the respective filters. Do NOT use 2 separate queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search in myTable for elements  where key's value is contained in myList1, myList2 you can either create a new List with the contents of each one or call the whereContainedIn method twice:

```
ParseQuery myQuery1 = new ParseQuery("myTable");
myQuery1.whereContainedIn("key", myList1);
myQuery1.whereContainedIn("key", myList2);
// Test first if the Query builder retains both lists or if myList1 is replaced with myList2

// OR

// Only use unique values
Set<T> mySet = new HashSet<T>();
set.addAll(myList1);
set.addAll(myList2);
List<T> myNewList = new ArrayList<T>(mySet);
ParseQuery myQuery1 = new ParseQuery("myTable");
myQuery1.whereContainedIn("key", myNewList);
```